# Unsupported address method 'v4tunnel'

Tags: ubuntu, ipv6, tunnel

I'm trying to create a tunnel to [HE.net](https://tunnelbroker.net) to get an IPv6 address on my (cloud) server.

When I created the tunnel and put this in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto he-ipv6
iface he-ipv6 inet6 v4tunnel
        address <my IPv6 address>
        netmask 64
        endpoint 66.220.7.82
        local <my IPv4 address>
        ttl 255
        gateway <my gateway>
```

Then `ifup he-ipv6`, and I got:

```
error: /etc/network/interfaces: line5: iface he-ipv6: unsupported address method 'v4tunnel'
```

How can I fix this?

The operating system is `Ubuntu 18.04.3`.

(I've tried to search this error but it seems nobody ever has it. But I've tried on two separate machine by different providers, and the results are the same.)

---

Update: add a picture for details:

[image: Click this]

---

Update 2: add a picture of netplan:

[image: Click this]

---

Conclusion: the problem is caused by **`ifupdown2`**.

Comment: The settings look correct - actually, specifics aside, identical to mine. What cloud provider/style of VPS? Might be something speicific to that.

Comment: wait, are there no ipv4 settings?

Comment: One is [Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute) from Google Cloud Platform, the other is [Elastic Compute Service](https://www.alibabacloud.com/product/ecs) from Alibaba Cloud Elastic Compute Service.

Comment: There is no IPv4 config in `/etc/network/interfaces` for default, but they both can get a public address automatically. `ifconfig` prints an interface named `eth0` with that address.

Comment: that's interesting. Is there a netplan config? That's the default for this version and I wonder if its using that or network manager... not very sure how precisely to check...

Comment: `/etc/network/interfaces` of Google Compute Engine points out that it is managed by netplan. I have updated a screenshot of that.

Comment: ah, could you try the (experimental) netplan config for HE? Its newish but might be the easiest way to get this working

Comment: Thanks! The provided netplan config doesn't work well (`ifconfig` shows `TX Error`), but a new interface is online. I'll try to fix it.

Comment: Oh! In which case *do* self answer once you get it to work. If it was a physical machine, least on 18.04, I'd go with removing netplan, but I'm worried about the prospect of breaking network totally on a cloud VM.

Comment: Yes, changing the network config of cloud VM is not so safe... By the way I've tried on a local Debian machine, and everything works well after edited `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Comment: Debian dosen't use netplan. It's one of Ubuntu's own quirks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### *ifupdown* versus *ifupdown2*

From your error message, you are using the package [*ifupdown2*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/ifupdown2) rather than [*ifupdown*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/ifupdown). Both are available on Ubuntu, but the online manpage shows only one version, I'm guessing the default installed, which would explain why you ended up using *ifupdown2*.

- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS: [interfaces(5)](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man5/interfaces.5.html)

  > Provided by: ifupdown_0.8.10ubuntu1_amd64
  >   [...]
  >
  > AUTHOR
  >   The ifupdown suite was written by Anthony Towns <aj@azure.humbug.org.au>.
- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS: [interfaces(5)](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/interfaces.5.html)

  > Provided by: ifupdown2_1.0~git20170314-1_all
  >   [...]
  >
  > AUTHOR
  >   Roopa Prabhu <roopa@cumulusnetworks.com>

While *ifupdown2* is a replacement for *ifupdown* [developped by Cumulus Networks](https://www.slideshare.net/CumulusNetworks/ifupdown2-network-interface-manager), with improved support for modern network features, there are some syntax incompatibilities.

So either install *ifupdown* instead of *ifupdown2*, or adapt the configuration, which I give below.

---

### What tunnel?

The original *ifupdown* provides the [v4tunnel method](https://manpages.debian.org/stable/ifupdown/interfaces.5#The_v4tunnel_Method):

> The v4tunnel Method
>
> This method may be used to setup an IPv6-over-IPv4 tunnel. It requires the ip command from the iproute package.

The *ifupdown* settings run these actual commands:

```
ip tunnel add he-ipv6 mode sit remote 66.220.7.82 local <my IPv4 address> ttl 255
ip link set he-ipv6 up
ip addr add <my IPv6 address> dev he-ipv6
ip route add <my gateway> dev he-ipv6
ip route add ::/0 via <my gateway> dev he-ipv6 onlink
```

So we know it's a [SIT](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2019/05/17/an-introduction-to-linux-virtual-interfaces-tunnels/#sit) tunnel.

---

### Using *ifupdown2*

The package *ifupdown2*, doesn't provide a `v4tunnel` method and lacks documentation for the replacement `tunnel` method which should have been described in [`man ifupdown-addons-interfaces`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/ifupdown-addons-interfaces.5.html) but is not. It's still available from `ifquery --syntax-help`. Here's an excerpt (from Ubuntu 18.04's version):

> ```
> tunnel: create/configure GRE/IPIP/SIT tunnel interfaces
> [...]
>   endpoint
>     help: IP of remote tunnel endpoint
>     required: True
>     validvals: <ipv4>,<ipv6>
>     example:
>       endpoint 192.2.0.23
>   local
>     help: IP of local tunnel endpoint
>     required: True
>     validvals: <ipv4>,<ipv6>
>     example:
>       local 192.2.0.42
>   mode
>     help: type of tunnel as in 'ip link' command.
>     required: True
>     validvals: greipip,sit
>     example:
>       mode gre
>   ttl
>     help: TTL for tunnel packets
>     required: False
>     validvals: <number>
>     example:
>       ttl 64
> ```

Note that there's a typo in *mode* values (it should be `gre,ipip,sit`). Newer versions would handle more modes (anyway we already have `sit` available):

> ```
>     validvals: gre,gretap,ipip,sit,vti,ip6gre,ipip6,ip6ip6,vti6
> ```

Which gives this working configuration:

```
auto he-ipv6
iface he-ipv6 inet6 tunnel
        mode sit
        address <my IPv6 address>
        netmask 64
        endpoint 66.220.7.82
        local <my IPv4 address>
        ttl 255
        gateway <my gateway>
```

The difference is the generic `tunnel` method and that you specify the type of tunnel with the `mode` keyword.

Comment: Switching to _ifupdown_ solves the problem. (By the way, both _ifupdown_ and _ifupdown2_ are not installed on the VM, so I just thought the newer should be better)